# If $M = P_1U_1$ and $N = P_2U_2$and $M$ and $N$ are unitarily equivalent then $P_1$ and $P_2$ are unitarily similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M, N \in M_n$.

- Let $M = P_1U_1$ and $N =P_2U_2$ be polar decompositions.($P_i$ is positive semidefinite and $U_i$ is unitary. )
- Suppose 
  $M$ and $N$ are unitarily equivalent.

Why are  $P_1$ and $P_2$  unitarily similar?

Comment: By polar decompositions, we know that ${P_1} = {(M{M^*})^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and ${P_2} = {(N{N^*})^{\frac{1}{2}}}$.And next ???

Answer (score 0):

M and N are unitarily equivalent, then $Q_1MQ_2=N$, $Q_1, Q_2$ are unitary matrics.
then $Q_2^*M^*Q_1^*=N^*$, --> $Q_1MQ_2 * Q_2^*M^*Q_1^*=NN^*$,-->$Q_1MM^*Q_1^*=NN^*$,
-->$Q_1P_1^2Q_1^*=P_2^2$, -->$(Q_1P_1Q_1^*)^2=P_2^2$, --> $P_2=Q_1P_1Q_1^*$,
then P1 and P2 are unitarily similar.
(note:according to the polar decomposition, $M=PU$,then we have $P=(AA^*)^{1/2}$, so $AA^*=P^2$).